# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have RowDatabound event where I want to change column names like this:

```
 Protected Sub gvKeyValueOfstringstring_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvKeyValueOfstringstring.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then

            gvKeyValueOfstringstring.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Match"
            gvKeyValueOfstringstring.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Replace"
        End If
    End Sub
```

but I am getting err:

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: Check how many column does your gridview `gvKeyValueOfstringstring` has?

Comment: a simple debug can give you the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `gvKeyValueOfstringstring.Columns` has a lenght less than 2, so when you access the column with index 0 or 1, it fails.

Check the columns are being created successfully before executing that code.

Also, I think you don't need to execute that in the RowDataBound event, it could be in `Page_Load` (so you don't have to check for every row if it's the header). If you anyway want to do it there, maybe you can just change the value of the cells of that Row:

```
e.Row.Cells(0).Text = "Match"
e.Row.Cells(1).Text = "Replace"
```

Anyway, I expect this code to also fail if the columns are not properly created.

Comment: Columns are autogenerated. gridview is bound with xml which has two columns

Comment: Maybe is because of that. Try the second option of just changing the cell text of the header row

Comment: what is second option. how to do it?

Comment: `e.Row.Cells(0).Text = "Match"`
`e.Row.Cells(1).Text = "Replace"`

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub BttnCan_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BttnCan.Click
        Dim val1 As Integer
        Try
            con.Open()
            For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count
                val1 = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value

                com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TblStock (Quant) VALUES (" & val1 & ")"

            Next

            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Any chance you would consider explaining this code, and why it is an answer to the question posed?